# Reference request: application of Minty - Browder theorem to a quasilinear elliptic pde problem

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

I am working on a research and I'm having a hard time understanding how to use Minty-Browder theorem on a quasilinear elliptic pde problem with a Neumann boundary condition. I am really looking for a beginner-friendly reference, and hoping for a detailed explanation of this approach.